# How to properly configure VSCode to format python code correctly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a problem formatting my python code in VSCode, when I specify the return type of a function the code seems to be no longer recognized correctly:

[image]

As you can see from the image, the code is no longer colored in the correct way, and this affects from the point where the function is defined until the next function declaration.

If it would be helpful, I leave my `setting.json` file:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "Scripts\\python.exe",
    "files.exclude" : {
        "Lib" : true,
        "lib" : true,
        "Include" : true,
        "Scripts" : true,
        "**/__pycache__": true
    }
}
```

I'm currently using **Python 3.8.7**

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8.7

Comment: PyLance is not a formatter, is is the Language Server, search for Python Formatters

Comment: Thanks for the correction and for the advice, I edited the question

Comment: The problem was that I had enabled the **Python for VSCode** extension as well as **Pylance**, once I disabled **Python for VSCode** the problem was solved.